# How to derive equation (upper bound for the period to-wavelength, grating)

Tags: optics

I am currently reading the paper entitled "Antireﬂection behavior of silicon subwavelength periodic structures for visible light" [P. Lalanne & G Michael Morris, [*Nanotechnology* **8**, 53 (1997)](https://doi.org/10.1088/0957-4484/8/2/002)].

On the first page, they write:

> To suppress Fresnel reﬂections for randomly polarized light, we
>   consider 2D SWS '(Subwavelength structured)' surfaces. The free parameters of the design are the
>   period $\Lambda$, the grating proﬁle and the depth. The period is related to
>   the smallest wavelength $\lambda_{min}$ so that, for a given angle of incidence
>   $\theta_i$, the SWS surface acts as a zero$^\mathrm{th}$-order ﬁlter by reﬂection. If the
>   reﬂected zero$^\mathrm{th}$ order alone is to propagate in the incident medium of
>   refractive index equal to 1, the upper bound for the
>   period to-wavelength ratio $\Lambda$/$\lambda_{min}$ is simply equal to 1/(1+sin($\theta_i$)).

I would like to know how they derived this, more specifically, why for $m=0$ (zero$^\mathrm{th}$ order) and an incident medium equal to $n=1$ (refractive index), we have:

$$\frac{\Lambda}{\lambda_{min}} = \frac{1}{1+\sin(\theta_i)}$$